# Enable CORS Ionic to send http

Tags: android, angular, ionic4, capacitor

I want to send an HTTP POST request by clicking a button to server, which is located at a different domain. Its working on POSTMAN

Below is the code

```
faceImageValidation(faceImage) {

    let headers =  {headers: new  HttpHeaders({ 
    'Content-Type':'application/json',
    'account-id': '8912292327fe',
    'api-key': '2c0652c54747'})
    }; 

   let postData = {
       "task_id": '74f4c926-250c-43ca-9c53-453e87ceacd1',
       "group_id": '8e16424a-58fc-4ba4-ab20-5bc8e7c3c41e',
       "data": {
       "document1": documentLink
       }
   };
   this.httpClient.post('https://eve.idfy.com/v3/tasks/sync/check_photo_liveness/face', JSON.stringify(postData),headers).subscribe(data => {
       console.log(data);
    },error =>{
              console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Below is the error

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://eve.idfy.com/v3/tasks/sync/check_photo_liveness/face' from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I also tried adding Access-Control-Allow-Origin in header but its still giving me error.

Comment: Please be sure to redact any potentially sensitive information (account ID, API keys) before posting. If these are production credentials, you'll want to rotate them ASAP.

Comment: Are you sure this is supposed to be implemented in JavaScript (client-side)?

Comment: CORS Policy has to be allowed from the server side (https://eve.idfy.com/v3/tasks/sync/check_photo_liveness/face) first, before it can accept such requests coming from your end (http://localhost:8100). Unless you use some browsers' CORS extension to enable cross-origin resource sharing.

Comment: I'm using 3rd party library, so it cant be done from server side

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is supposed to be implemented in JavaScript (client-side)? If it works in Postman, it's likely due to direct HTTP requests where CORS isn't a factor. The destination resource (i.e. eve.idfy.com) would have to send "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" indicating it will accept a request from your JavaScript origin (localhost) which technically isn't possible.

I would advise implementing your API using server-side code and provide yourself with your own local, CORS-friendly endpoint for your client-side code to load from if it's still absolutely necessary. This will also help to mitigate disclosure of *your* API access credentias.

See also [Deadly CORS when http://localhost is the origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883211)